# Highchart from json object

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

i have a 2 arrays like

```
x-titles=["16/06/2014", "16/06/2014", "16/06/2014", "17/06/2014", "18/06/2014", "18/06/2014"];
y_titles=["2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"];
```

from this i want to create a `highchart` . date as`x-axis`  and total_booking as y-axis .
i have done this as [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nisham/LLExL/3053/).but i am unable to create charts. can anyone tell what is the issue.

Comment: Have a look at how JSON is formatted http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Comment: actually i am using an php array. ihave json_encode this array. and displayed in console.  this is how i am getting in console.

Comment: @Ondkloss  i have changed json object to arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were originally using incorrect formatting for you JSON.

With your updated question you can directly fill the `x_titles` and `y_titles` arrays, which are used by the Highchart.

The problem with the two arrays presented in your question is that the `x-titles` variable has a dash (`-`) in it's name, so it needs to be `x_titles`. Also that the values for `y_titles` need to be numeric values (not textstrings) to show on the Y-axis.

[Modified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/3060/)

Comment: I used your Fiddle and made an update to it, here: [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/3060/). Just see the top two lines.

Comment: .how to make x axis as datetime.